# Hoffman Linear algebra section 1.5 exercise 6

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So I'm self studying Hoffman and Kunzes' linear algebra book (really good by the way) and I wanted to have a go at this problem since it is a fundamental property used throughout the book:

Let $A$ be a $m \hspace{1mm}\times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n \hspace{1mm}\times k$ matrix. Show that the columns of $C=AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$. If $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}...\alpha_{n}$ are the columns of $A$, and $\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2}...\gamma_{k}$ are the columns of $C$, then
$$\gamma_{j}=\sum_{r=1}^n B_{rj}\alpha_{r}$$

My proof: 
Using the definition of matrix multiplication, we have that the matrix $C=AB$ can be described as follows:
$$C_{ij}=\sum_{r=1}^n A_{ir}B_{rj}$$
Now, the $j$th column of matrix $C$ is:
$$\gamma_{j}=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{1j} \\
C_{2j} \\
: \\
C_{mj}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{r=1}^n A_{1r}B_{rj} \\
\sum_{r=1}^n A_{2r}B_{rj} \\
: \\
\sum_{r=1}^n A_{mr}B_{rj}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We now note that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_{1r} \\
A_{2r} \\
: \\
A_{mr}
\end{bmatrix}$$
simply denotes the $rth$ column of matrix $A$ where $1 \leq r \leq n$. All components of the column, or $m \times 1$ matrix are multiplied by the same constant $B_{rj}$ within the summation sign. By the rules of matrix scalar multiplication, we write:
$$\gamma_{j}= \sum_{r=1}^{n} \left(B_{rj} \begin{bmatrix}
A_{1r} \\
A_{2r} \\
: \\
A_{mr}
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{n}B_{rj} \alpha_{r}$$
Q.E.D

Thoughts?

Comment: Your proof is fine. I prefer the vector notation. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^k$ denote the standard  bases. Then $Cf_j$ is the $j$th column of $C$  while $Ae_r$ is the $r$th column of $A.$ We have  $Bf_j=\sum_{r=1}^n B_{rj}e_r.$ Thus $$\gamma_j=Cf_j=ABf_j=\sum_{r=1}^n B_{rj}Ae_r=\sum_{r=1}^n B_{rj}a_r$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Could you further elaborate why $Bf_{j}=\sum_{r=1}^n B_{rj}e_{r}$?

Comment: $Bf_j$ is the $j$th column of $B,$ i.e. it is the vector with $n$ coordinates equal $B_{rj}$ at position $r$ for $1\le r\le n.$ The vector $e_r$ has $n$ coordinates: $1$ at position $r$ and $0$ at other positions. That's why $Bf_j=\sum_{r=1}^nB_{rj} e_r.$